# Difference of two IntVectors in Rpy

Tags: rpy2, subtraction

`a` and `b` are both rpy2 `IntVector`s:

```
<IntVector - Python:0x10676dfc8 / R:0x7fc714d64948>
[      81, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, ...,      120,       46, NA_integer_]
```

How can I calculate the `b - a` difference? I want the result as an `IntVector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [R operator attribute .ro](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/vector.html#operators):

```
In [1]: from rpy2 import robjects

In [2]: x = robjects.IntVector(range(10))

In [3]: y = robjects.IntVector(range(10))

In [4]: x.ro-y
Out[4]: 
<IntVector - Python:0x1067d3830 / R:0x102d6ef20>
[       0,        0,        0, ...,        0,        0,        0]

In [5]: x.ro+y
Out[5]: 
<IntVector - Python:0x1067d3cf8 / R:0x102d6eec8>
[       0,        2,        4, ...,       14,       16,       18]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
subtract  = r('''function(x, y) x - y''')
subtract(b, a)
```

The good about this solution is that it can not only handle IntVectors, but any R type.
The bad is that passing commands as strings to the R interpreter is ugly.